# SELECT BY "Blocks" of a field. Is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting crazy about this query that I am trying to do. 
 I have Google it, forums but unfortunately no luck to find the solution.

Let me explain what I am trying to achieve:

I have this table:

```
+----------+-------------+
|Advert_Id | Advert_Type |
+----------+-------------+ 
|       1  | 1           |
|       2  | 3           |
|       3  | 1           |
|       4  | 2           |
|       5  | 2           |
|       6  | 3           |
|       7  | 1           |
|       8  | 1           | 
|       9  | 1           | 
|      10  | 1           | 
|      11  | 1           | 
|      12  | 1           | 
+----------+-------------+
```

**What I need:**

Select a **RAND Advert_Id** with the **ORDER BY Advert_Type** in "BLOCKS" OF 4 (from 3 to 1 eg. 3,2,1 and 1 again) 
 So, firt block will be 3,2,1,1 second block 3,2,1,1 and so on...

**Expect output should be:**

```
+----------+-------------+ 
|Advert_Id | Advert_Type | 
+----------+-------------+ 
|        2 | 3           |
|        4 | 2           |
|        9 | 1           |
|       12 | 1           |
|        6 | 3           |
|        5 | 2           |
|        1 | 1           |
|        8 | 1           |
|       10 | 1           | 
|        3 | 1           | 
|       11 | 1           | 
|        7 | 1           | 
+----------+-------------+
```

What I am trying to achieve is: I have a table ADVERT with a lot of adverts so each advert has a type ADVERT_TYPE (1, 2 or 3).
So I need to show on my website one advert type 3, then another with type 2, then another two adverts with type 1. As you can see with this we have a block of four adverts. The same will be applied to the others.
But as you can see on my table. I have more adverts with type 1 so it will just repeat until i display all.

thanks again,

Comment: You want ORDER BY to take only the first row with a certain vaule for a certain column and then append rows from the lower end until you have four rows in your result set?
Sounds like your design is bad. Please tell us what you wish to achieve.

Comment: What's the logic behind that ordering? I can't see a pattern.

Comment: I have explain what I am trying to achieve. But now sure if is possible. Without coding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do it exactly like this in MySQL

There are 2 ways I would try to resolve this issue after MySQL

1) Do it programmatically after the query

eg. load all Advert_Type = 3 into an array and All 2's into an array and all 1's into another and merging them.

2) Add a level field in your table and simply order by level (of course any randomness that you were maybe hoping for goes out the window)

Comment: Yes, I have done this by PHP and works. But the problem is how I can do a pagination with PHP without repeating the same adverts. Its really a pain!

Comment: @dops. If you're using RAND() then I'd say you're obliged to do the pagination in PHP!

Comment: @Strawberry I retract my answer then ;)

Comment: Oops - meant @user3507330

Comment: Ok, and if I dont use RAND. Is it possible without code? I mean only using SQL? it's hard isn't it?

Comment: @user3507330 without RAND then the only way I could do it is adding a extra field to order them by, then writing an admin section to reorder them programmatically.